# Non null relationships in primary constructor of entity

Tags: kotlin, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm creating application with Spring Data Neo4j and Kotlin. I use standard kotlin way to declare entities (class with primary constructor). Everything worked fine until I wanted to create simple, one-to-many and mandatory relationship between my entities. When I'm calling `.findAll()` on my repository I get `Parameter specified as non-null is null: method ...model.Campaign.<init>, parameter client`.

I tried to call `.findAll(depth = 1)` to load related entities to my entity but that didn't help.

```
@NodeEntity
class User(var name: String)
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null
}

@NodeEntity
class Campaign(
    var name: String,
    @Relationship(type = "CLIENT", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    var client: User)
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null
}

interface CampaignRepository : Neo4jRepository<Campaign, Long>

//...

campaignRepository.save(Campaign("C1", user))

campaignRespository.findAll()
```

Of course, I can just declare `var client: User?` as nullable and everything is fine. But, since in my model I will have both mandatory and optional relationships I want to know if there's a way to overcome this.

Comment: Are you sure that all the campaigns you actually fetched have a client?

Comment: in my test case I call `campaignRepository.deleteAll()` just before inserting this

Comment: so, there's no chance that some other campaign is trying to map to non-null field

Comment: Since the `client` is a `var`, maybe you somehow can use `lateinit` to fix it?

Comment: in kotlin you cannot use `lateinit` on primary constructor parameters

Comment: No, you would have to remove it from the constructor. Maybe Spring Data Neo4J can set the property with a setter or something (ref the "somehow" in my last comment)?

Comment: but, how i can place non-nullable property without initializer? if it's non nullable I have to initialize it in primary constructor

Comment: @kubawar You don't have to in initialize it in the primary constructor if the property is `lateinit`.

Comment: i found a solution based on your suggestions but it's not very elegant. i'll post it as an answer but if you have any other ideas, please publish them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but not very elegant:

```
@NodeEntity
class Campaign(
    var name: String,
    client: User?)
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null

    @Relationship(type = "CLIENT", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    lateinit var client: User

    init
    {
        client?.let { this.client = it }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an semi-official workaround to this issue available [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1148?focusedCommentId=182284&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-182284). Quite a lot of extra code but does do the job